# Stata: use of cluster or svy with standardized coefficients

Tags: stata, standardized

I got the recommendation to standardize my regression coefficients.
I have never done it before, but I have seen it in papers, it seems quite common.
At first sight it appeared quite simple, just adding the `beta` option to the `regress` command in Stata.

However, since I have individuals in groups, I need to use the cluster `option` as well.
Now Stata tells me that using both options together is not possible:
`beta may not be specified with vce(cluster clustvar) or the svy prefix`.
The manual does not say why.

Using the user written command `listcoef` I can get the betas for my regression.
The question now is, is this a computational problem Stata has and I can safely use the `listcoef` results or is this a statistical problem and I cannot use them or only under certain conditions.

I cannot see a statistical reason why Stata should not be able to do this.
My Google searches came up with other people having the same question, but no explanation of whether this is a statistical or computational problem.

I am happy for any feedback. Potentially I used the wrong search terms?
I cannot believe I am the first to wonder about this.

Comment: Better asked on Statalist. By Stack Overflow standards, this is at best dubious because you don't have a programming problem that you pose. By Cross Validated standards, this is also dubious because this is phrased in terms of difficulties in using Stata. Statalist doesn't recognise any such boundaries. But why were you recommended to standardize; you don't say why. (Again, that is immaterial here.)

Comment: I removed the tag cluster-analysis. This has nothing to do with finding clusters.

Comment: Agree that this is completely off-topic for SO but could be asked on Statalist. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done for statistical reasons. Standardized coefficients are defined as ratios of variances of some kind. In turn, Stata is only willing to think about variance decomposition when the data are i.i.d. Specifying robust or cluster or svy variance estimation indicates to Stata that data are not i.i.d., hence it refuses to produce standardized coefficients for you. If you know exactly what the standardized coefficients are, and how to compute them, and are sure that listcoef does exactly what's needed, it may be the case that listcoef's results are usable; I can't advise either way.

Agree with Nick and Steve that this is off topic though.